# Conditional Operators not performing as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to compare two sets of returned values from user selects, but when I go to compare the data from the results, the elseif statement defaults, despite the information being clearly the opposite. It doesn't matter what the values are, the program always refers to the elseif. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

```
// DB Constant Defines
define('DB_NAME','NurseData'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD','root'); 
define('DB_HOST','localhost'); 

$state1 = $_REQUEST['state1'];
$state2 = $_REQUEST['state2'];
$city1 = $_REQUEST['city1'];
$city2 = $_REQUEST['city2'];
$jobTitle1 = $_REQUEST['job1'];
$jobTitle2 = $_REQUEST['job2'];

function showerror() {
    die("Error " . mysql_errno() . " : " . mysql_error());
}

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT
    TOT_EMP,  
    JOBS_1000,
    A_MEAN,
    A_PCT90
    FROM Nurse_Local 
    WHERE PRIM_STATE='" . $state1 . "' 
    AND AREA_NAME='" . $city1 . "' 
    AND OCC_TITLE='" . $jobTitle1 . "'";

$query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT
    TOT_EMP,  
    JOBS_1000,
    A_MEAN,
    A_PCT90
    FROM Nurse_Local 
    WHERE PRIM_STATE='" . $state2 . "' 
    AND AREA_NAME='" . $city2 . "' 
    AND OCC_TITLE='" . $jobTitle2 . "'";

if (!($getPosts1 = mysql_query ($query1, $connection))) {
    showerror();
}

if (!($getPosts2 = mysql_query ($query2, $connection))) {
    showerror();
}


while($rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($getPosts1)) {     

    while($rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($getPosts2)) {

    //Retrieve array values
        for ($i1 = 0; $i1 < count($rows1); $i1++) {
            for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < count($rows2); $i2++) {
                //Assign array values
                $tot_EMP1 = $rows1['TOT_EMP'];
                $tot_EMP2 = $rows2['TOT_EMP'];
                $jobs_PER1 = $rows1['JOBS_1000'];
                $jobs_PER2 = $rows2['JOBS_1000'];
                $a_MEAN1 = $rows1['A_MEAN'];
                $a_MEAN2 = $rows2['A_MEAN'];
                $A_PCT901 = $rows1['A_PCT90'];
                $A_PCT902 = $rows2['A_PCT90'];

                //Convert array values to numbers
                $tot_EMP1 = 0 + $tot_EMP1;
                $tot_EMP2 = 0 + $tot_EMP2;

                //Functions for calculating differences
                /*
                function compareEMP1($diffEMP1) {
                    $diffEMP1 = $rows1['TOT_EMP'] - $rows2['TOT_EMP'];
                    return $diffEMP1;
                }

                function compareEMP2() {
                    $diffEMP2 = $rows2['TOT_EMP'] - $rows1['TOT_EMP'];
                    return $diffEMP2;
                }
            */
            }
        }

        if($tot_EMP1 > $tot_EMP2 || $tot_EMP2 < $tot_EMP1) {
            echo $tot_EMP1;//"In " . $state1 . " there are " . compareEMP1() . " more jobs than in " . $state2;
        }
        elseif ($tot_EMP2 > $tot_EMP1 || $tot_EMP1 < $tot_EMP2) {
            echo $tot_EMP2;//"In " . $state2 . " there are " . compareEMP2() . " more jobs than in " . $state1;
        }
        else {
            echo "<p>There was a problem comparing the employment numbers.</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly indent the code properly. It's a mess right now.

Comment: I'll try, but I'm all self-taught so I don't really know what good indentation looks like.

Comment: It looks like the indentation used for your functions

Comment: Is that better? I tried to remove excess empty lines and align functions properly within each other.

Comment: this seems redundant `$tot_EMP1 > $tot_EMP2 || $tot_EMP2 < $tot_EMP1` - if tot1 is less than tot2 **or tot2 is greater than tot1** could be said as if tot1 **not equal** tot2

Comment: It is redundant, a moment of frustration trying to force the conditional operators to work properly. Also I do need at least one greater than/less than comparison operator, since the results will say which has more of X.

Comment: Not sure how this code is working because you are missing a few braces.

Comment: EDIT: Looks like it didn't work, I edited my code to include the (embarassingly) missing braces.

Ha! I think that did it. Not enough sleep... I'll fix that after lunch, and see what happens. I'll get back to it. Thank you for spotting it.

Comment: @tourniquet_grab: Just noticed the braces too.

Comment: That is why I asked you to indent the code properly. Never underestimate the power of good indentation. Are you trying to print the larger value?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to print the larger value. This is currently just in testing so once I'm able to accurately print the larger value, I'll be applying it to the rest of the variables.

Comment: @tourniquet_grab Back from lunch, and you are correct that I'm trying to print the larger value.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it was because the "numbers" were being outputted as strings, and PHP wasn't recognizing them as numbers. I resolved it by first performing a str_replace on both $tot_EMP1 and $tot_EMP2 to remove the commas and then performing a intval() on both variables. This converts them to an integer, and the logic performs as desired. Now I will need to figure out how to add the commas back in and preserve the int status of the results.

The actual code that did the converting, but please keep in mind that my DB has the info stored as strings, so part of the problem was my own failure to properly store the data:

```
                //Assign individual array values
                $tot_EMP1 = $rows1['TOT_EMP'];
                $tot_EMP2 = $rows2['TOT_EMP'];
                $jobs_PER1 = $rows1['JOBS_1000'];
                $jobs_PER2 = $rows2['JOBS_1000'];
                $a_MEAN1 = $rows1['A_MEAN'];
                $a_MEAN2 = $rows2['A_MEAN'];
                $a_PCT901 = $rows1['A_PCT90'];
                $a_PCT902 = $rows2['A_PCT90'];


                //Convert individual array values to numbers
                $tot_EMP1 = str_replace(",", "", $tot_EMP1);
                $tot_EMP2 = str_replace(",", "", $tot_EMP2);
                $tot_EMP1 = intval($tot_EMP1);
                $tot_EMP2 = intval($tot_EMP2);
                $jobs_PER1 = floatval($jobs_PER1);
                $jobs_PER2 = floatval($jobs_PER2);
                $a_MEAN1 = str_replace(",", "", $a_MEAN1);
                $a_MEAN2 = str_replace(",", "", $a_MEAN2);
                $a_MEAN1 = intval($a_MEAN1);
                $a_MEAN2 = intval($a_MEAN2);
                $a_PCT901 = str_replace(",", "", $a_PCT901);
                $a_PCT902 = str_replace(",", "", $a_PCT902);
                $a_PCT901 = intval($a_PCT901);
                $a_PCT902 = intval($a_PCT902);
```

Comment: That sounds like you were not using a proper numerical data type to begin with, but have been storing strings instead – that is something you should fix. If you want different decimal points or thousand separators when _displaying_ those numbers, then that is an issue of _formatting_.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately they're stored as strings within the DB. It's not a particularly easy switch when trying to convert to INT (at least from my experience of trying to blanket convert from VARCHAR to INT/FLOAT) so this hack works well enough.